# How to remove objects within a todo?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code for my current todo list.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ToDo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    function addText(){
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        var node = document.createElement("P");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(input);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById('do').appendChild(node);
    }
    </script>

    <p id="do"> </p>
    <input type='text' id='input'/>
    <input type='button' onclick='addText()' value='Add To List'/>
</body>
</html>
```

It works to add objects but I have no idea what the javascript is to remove objects?

I wonder if someone could help me with a remove script like a X mark on the side of a new added object or something just to remove 1 after you add it,

Cheers

Comment: You'll need `removeChild`. It should be fairly simple, so give it a shot and see if you can come up with anything :)

Comment: Did you mean, removing the child element? then use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)

Comment: I don't understand your above comments, but I feel that you have misunderstood the way of using `document.getElementById("addText")`.  The example in the w3school is little complicated, look into MDN in my above comment.

Comment: This is how it works right now!

http://jsfiddle.net/rC9zW/

But how do I specifict what object I want to remove?

instead of just removing the first object added so want I be able to remove ANY object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution to your problem. Check my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kq4NF/

```
var c = 1;
function addText(){
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var node = document.createElement("P");
    node.setAttribute('id', 'anchor'+c);
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(input);
    node.appendChild(textnode);

    var removenode = document.createElement("input");
    removenode.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    removenode.setAttribute('value', 'X');
    removenode.setAttribute("onclick", "removeText('anchor"+c+"')");
    node.appendChild(removenode);
    c++;
    document.getElementById('do').appendChild(node);
}

function removeText(item){
    var child=document.getElementById(item);
    document.getElementById('do').removeChild(child);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what i asked for!

Thank you so much for showing me how it works, this will help me alot in my project!

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.getElementById("do"); 
list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
```

`list` - represents the `p` tag with ID `do`
`list.ChildNodes` - list of child elements appended to your **`p`** tag with `ID` as `do`.
`list.ChildNodes[0]` - represents the ***first child*** appended to the list, where `0` is the index.

To remove a *specific element*, either represent the is as *index* or point directly the element like

```
var list = document.getElementById("do"); 
var node = document.createElement("P");
var textnode = document.createTextNode(input);
textnode.id = "do1";  // Add id to the child element
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById('do').appendChild(node);

// This is to remove it using ID
list.removeChild(document.getElementById("do1"));
```

Hope you can understand.